# Search functionality django

Tags: django

I've been following the tango with django book and I came across the search chapter using Bing's Search API. I tried to use it but it seems like Bing no longer offers those services. Now I want to make the search functionality local so that it could just search through my categories in the rango app but I don't know how to do this without the Bing search API. Anyone who could help me with a way around it if there is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't ask questions like this. To help you "get started" take a look at http://haystacksearch.org its the common standard for Django apps (in combination with elastic search backend) or use something like http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0b1/search/index.html wagtail search. Really easy to configure but not that powerful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to implement basic `search` in django:

**1) templates/base.html**

note: use `GET` method to get search input from `form`.

```
<form name="exampleform" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
```

**2) views.py**

```
def search(request):
    try:
        if 'q' in request.GET:# this will be GET now 
            querystring = request.GET.get('q')# passing in the query value to search view using the 'q' parameter
            if len(querystring) == 0:
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                pass
    except:
        pass

    results = {}

    if 'q' in request.GET:
        querystring = request.GET.get('q')
        if querystring is not None:
            results = UserModel.objects.filter(
                Q(email__icontains=querystring) |
                Q(first_name__icontains=querystring) |
                Q(last_name__icontains=querystring)).order_by('pk')# filter returns a list
            context = {'results': results}
            template = 'templates/search_result.html'
            return render(request, template, context)
        else:
            return redirect('index')
            context = {}
    else:
        return render(request, "templates/search_result.html")
```

**2) urls.py**

```
url(r'^search',views.search, name='search'),
```

**3) templates/search_result.html**

```
{% for each_object in results %} // results is list here so pick each element object using for loop 
    <a href="{% url 'user_detail' pk=each_object.pk %}">
    <!--Upon successful search object image with hyperlink appears -->
    <img src="{{each_object.image.url}}" alt="No Image"></a>
    <p>{{each_object.email}}</p>
    <p>{{each_object.first_name}}</p>
    <p>{{each_object.last_name}}</p>    
{% endfor %}
```

There are a few projects around to do search. Here's a non-exhaustive list: `djangosearch, django-search (with a dash), django-sphinx.`

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of thing I was looking for. @Emil George James

Comment: You didn't add the urls.py for the results.html

Comment: @Allen Sorry , it should be `search_result.html` not `result.html`.

Comment: @Allen Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the tick button.